# Как использовать в Perl скобки как символы в выражении типа "( ((345) ) )"?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Подскажите пожалуйста, как использовать в Perl скобки как символы в выражении типа "( ((345) ) )"? Кавычки конечно не в счет, искомое выражение без кавычек. В Perl не разбираюсь, а гугление все время выкидыает на страницы, где скобки рассматриваются как функциональная часть выражения, никак не могу нагуглить, как использовать их именно как символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решиилось экранированием через обратный слеш - "/" Т.е.: `"/(/(345/) /) /)"` (без кавычек естественно).

Comment: Вообще-то у вас написано с прямым слэшем. И что-то сомневаюсь, что так оно работает, потому что нужен обратный.

Answer (score 2):

[Тыц](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) - ссылка на раздел документации рег. выражений в perl, в котором обсуждается экранирование метасимволов.